# Failing to cast to generic array

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, casting

Hi I have the following extension method

```
    public static T[] GetComponentsOfType<T>(this GameObject source) where T : MonoBehaviour
    {
        Component[] matchingComponents = source.GetComponents<Component>().Where(comp => comp is T).ToArray();
        T[] castedComponents = new T[matchingComponents.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < matchingComponents.Length; i++)
        {
            castedComponents[i] = (T) matchingComponents[i];
        }
        return castedComponents;
    }
```

Which works completely fine however I tried to shorten it by just a single line

```
 return (T[]) source.GetComponents<Component>().OfType<T>().Cast<Component>().ToArray();
```

And apparently this line fails to cast the `Component[]` to `T[]` but when I cast each element separately it works (the first example). Why is that ?

Comment: Well yes - if you've created a `Component[]`, that *isn't* a `FooComponent[]` or whatever `T` is. Why not just use `OfType<T>().ToArray()`? Why are you calling `Cast<Component>()`?

Comment: `Cast<Component>()` doesn't make sense. If you want `T`'s, why cast it to `Component` again?

Comment: Resharper made me do it @JonSkeet :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
source.GetComponents<Component>().OfType<T>().ToArray();
```

To do it in one line.

The cast fails because you are casting two types that do not match and Array of component to and array of T and that is invalid.

Comment: What do you expect the `Select` to do?

Answer (score 2):

You should make use of the `OfType<>` only. In your solution, you are it back to `Component`, which can't be cast to T[], so thats the problem.

The `OfType<>` already casts it. It's like a substitute for `Where(item => item is T).Cast<T>()`

```
return source.GetComponents<Component>().OfType<T>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Indeed `return source.GetComponents<Component>().OfType<T>().ToArray();` is completely enough for the task thank you for the quick response !

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen: But you've stlil got the actual cast operator `(T[])`. That's unnecessary, as the return type of `ToArray()` will already be `T[]`.